# How can I get Eclipse to make assumptions about my template parameters?

Tags: templates, ide, eclipse-cdt, indexer

I have

```
template <typename T> class Foo : public T { /* ... */ }
```

and I only instantiate it with `T`s which are subclasses of `Bar`. If it helps, I can static_assert that's the case.

So, Eclipse CDT doesn't recognize T is "really" also a `Bar`. I can't complain about that - but can I *make* it understand that? That is, can I somehow tell the Indexer to look for methods and types in class `Bar` as a base class of `Foo`?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good question!

Currently, there is no way to tell Eclipse that a template will only be instantiated with arguments that are subclasses of a particular type.

However, there is an upcoming C++ language feature that will allow you to express this relationship in your code, and for Eclipse to pick up on it as well: **[Concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B))**.

Concepts allow you to **constrain** template parameters such that they have to satisfy a **concept**, which can be thought of as a type predicate - a boolean function on types, evaluated at compile-time.

For example, you can write a concept like this:

```
template <typename T>
concept bool DerivedFromBar = std::is_base_of<Bar, T>::value;
```

This defines a concept `DerivedFromBar` which is satisfied only by types that are derived from `Bar`.

You can then use this concept in your class template definition:

```
template <DerivedFromBar T> class Foo : public T { /* ... */ }
```

Note the use of `DerivedFromBar` instead of the usual `typename` to declare the template parameter `T`. This tells the compiler that `T` is constrained to satisfy `DerivedFromBar`.

Once you express your code in this way, Eclipse can, in principle, make inferences that would allow it to offer members of `Bar` as auto-completion proposals when calling a method on an object of type `T` inside the template.

Concepts is currently supported by [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html#tses), with other compilers such as MSVC and clang working on implementing it.

[Bug 492682](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=492682) tracks Concepts support in Eclipse CDT. Taking advantage of Concepts for better auto-completion would then be a follow-up feature.